# Send data from android app to mysql without using get method

Tags: android, mysql

How to send data from android app to mysql database without using **get method** in the url like this

```
"www.test.com/send.php?user="+username+"pass="+password
```

Because for passwords it is not secured

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send data to your sever, use the `POST` request, and encrypt the user's data.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing stopping anyone from sniffing your network traffic if you use a GET or a POST.

The only way to "securely" authenticate is to hash the password on the device before you send it "across the wire"

Other alternatives involve Oauth or JWT, but seems to broad for what you're asking for

Answer (score 0):

I assume you made Send.php? If so, you can just keep the SQL username and password hardcoded in the PHP file. Since PHP is executed server side, there will be no network traffic in or out of your server containing the username and password.

For example, with the following PHP:

```
mysqli.connect(server, user, pass, db)
```

you can just hardcode in the user and pass and not use `$_REQUEST` to receive it. Since it will be executed within the server, there's no chance for stolen credentials.

If you are committed to the prospect of sending the credentials though, there is a solution. Once you have a solid username and password, generate an SHA-1 hash of the password. This is a unique string to the password, and cannot be reverse-engineered to find out the password. Keep this hash in the PHP file, and when the android user attempts to log in, hash the password and send it in the HTTP request. If the hash he sends lines up with the hash held by the server, we have authentication!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the question is asking about a login/registration system, not authentication against the database